# Cannot Install tinker Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, tinker

Cannot install tinker on Laravel 5.1. Composer version is `1.9.0`.
Here is the composer log: https://pastebin.com/aajb0m7p
I tried to remove vendor folder and install back, but that doesn't help. Is there any workaround? I would like to use tinker to test some of my API endpoints and don't waste time doing that by using UI.

**UPD** I'm getting these conflict messages because I have installed `lumen-framework 5.1.7` which requires `symfony/var-dumper 2.7.*`. But the earlier version of `tinker 1.0.0` and it requires at least `symfony/var-dumper ~3.0`. Is there any other workaround for me to test my Laravel endpoints without using UI?

Comment: backup your composer.lock, then delete and try again

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, no result :(

Comment: Woah, that's an old installation of Laravel. Why not use Laravel 6.X? Or released yesterday, Laravel 7!

Comment: no result? or same result?

Comment: @GarfieldLasaga as suggested by @Qirel why not update tout `laravel` version. Or at least update `laravel/lumen-framework`

Comment: Well you have to update your lumen

Comment: @GrenierJ I have a large code base and simply afraid of getting some unexpected errors in the back end

Comment: If you want to test you API you can always use [postman](https://www.postman.com/). You can also write functionnal tests with [`phpunit`](https://phpunit.de/) or any other test framework.

Answer (score 2):

As written in [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/tinker#v1.0.10), `tinker` need `symfony/var-dumper` on `~3.0|~4.0` but it seems that you have `2.7.51` installed. Try to update `symfony/var-dumper` to at least `3.0` then require `laravel/tinker`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, if it's possible, can you take a look please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a package which has a dependency to `symfony/var-dumper` on some version

and also the version of laravel tinker that you are trying to install also has dependency on different `symfony/var-dumper` version and they get conflict in version

so in your case what you can do is to find the package which uses `symfony/var-dumper` and update it to have same dependency with laravel tinker <strike>**OR** you can install a specific version of laravel tinker which has a lower dependency on symfony var dumper</strike>

for example : `composer require laravel/tinker:^1.0.1`

Comment: The version you propose will not work as composer already try it : `Installation request for laravel/tinker ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.10, v1.0.2, v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v1.0.5, v1.0.6, v1.0.7, v1.0.8, v1.0.9].`.

Comment: @GrenierJ I really liked your answer +1

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, if it's possible, can you take a look please?